# Can't Load a .Net Core 3.0 Web App Running From CLI

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

### Issue:

I have a .Net Core 3.0 app that I'm unable to load in a browser **ONLY when running it using the Mac OS X CLI**, like so:

```
$ dotnet new webapp
$ dotnet watch run
watch : Started
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile is available. Using '/Users/<user>/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' as key repository; keys will not be encrypted at rest.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /Users/<user>/Sandbox/coreapp3test
```

So everything looks good at this point, except when opening the URL in a browser I receive:

```
This site cannot be reached

localhost unexpectedly closed the connection.
```

### UPDATE:

I think it has something to do with HTTPS protocol.  Navigating to `http://localhost:5000` does render an https redirect.  So the server is actually listening...

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 9.6705ms 307
```

### UPDATE 2:

Furthermore, removing the `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` from the `Configure` method of `startup.cs` and then navigating to `http://localhost:5000` renders the page correctly, while `https://localhost:5001` still fails.

I've [opened a ticket on GitHub to track the issue.](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/3811)

### Notes:

- **I can run the app in VS Code**, so the runtime must be installed correctly
- **.NET Core 2.2 apps work fine with the CLI** - I can run them from the CLI without issue. So it appears isolated to 3.0
- **The Windows CLI appears to work without issue**
- I've also tried the following, without success:

  - Removing `bin/` and `obj/` and restoring / building again
  - Re-installing the SDK - same result
  - Disabling firewall (in case that was blocking the connection)
  - Generating multiple web project types (e.g. angular, mvc, etc.) to see if it was related to the template

### System Info:

```
$ dotnet --info

.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.0.100
 Commit:    04339c3a26

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Mac OS X
 OS Version:  10.14
 OS Platform: Darwin
 RID:         osx.10.14-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.0.100/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.0.0
  Commit:  7d57652f33

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.300 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  2.1.402 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  2.1.505 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  3.0.100 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.4 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.9 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.4 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.9 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.4 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.9 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## v3.1 Update

This has been resolved in v3.1.x, [per the dotnet team on Github](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/3811#issuecomment-547546091).

Answer (score 1):

running from vs code does `dotnet run`. It appears that the `watch` command has an infinite loop trying to watch some files that are contantly changing. This may be due to for example `reloadOnChange` option in `configurationBuilder`.

```
configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile(
            "appsettings.json",
            optional: false,
            reloadOnChange: true)
```

Comment: Good guess, but unfortunately still not working.  I did try running without the watcher too (i.e. `$ dotnet run`) but the result is the same.  I also removed the `configurationBuilder` pieces too (as I did have `reloadOnChange: true` for `appsettings.json`), but that didn't resolve either.  So I don't think this is specific to the watcher.

Comment: Interesting note: running the DLL directly (i.e. `$ dotnet bin/debug/netcoreapp3.0/<myapp>.dll`) works just fine.